# Count the occurrence of different numbers in file with awk (or grep)

Tags: file, awk, count, grep

I have file that contains different values in each line and I would like to count the occurrence of numbers that occurs after a specific keyword. For example;

```
  "fields" : {
    "referer" : [ "-" ],
    "@timestamp" : [ "2017-01-08T19:50:19.000Z" ],
    "uri_path" : [ "test" ],
    "method" : [ "GET" ],
    "servername" : [ "INMESPWEB03" ],
    "useragent" : [ "Mediapartners-Google" ],
    "querystring" : [ "test" ],
    "bytes-sent" : [ "227905" ],
    "cshost" : [ "www.test.com" ],
    "scstatus" : [ "200" ],
    "time-taken" : [ "15468" ]
  }
  "fields" : {
    "referer" : [ "-" ],
    "@timestamp" : [ "2017-01-08T19:50:19.000Z" ],
    "uri_path" : [ "test" ],
    "method" : [ "GET" ],
    "servername" : [ "INMESPWEB03" ],
    "useragent" : [ "Mediapartners-Google" ],
    "querystring" : [ "test" ],
    "bytes-sent" : [ "227905" ],
    "cshost" : [ "www.test.com" ],
    "scstatus" : [ "300" ],
    "time-taken" : [ "15468" ]
  }
  "fields" : {
    "referer" : [ "-" ],
    "@timestamp" : [ "2017-01-08T19:50:19.000Z" ],
    "uri_path" : [ "test" ],
    "method" : [ "GET" ],
    "servername" : [ "INMESPWEB03" ],
    "useragent" : [ "Mediapartners-Google" ],
    "querystring" : [ "test" ],
    "bytes-sent" : [ "227905" ],
    "cshost" : [ "www.test.com" ],
    "scstatus" : [ "200" ],
    "time-taken" : [ "15468" ]
  }
```

So the result should be like

- 200 : 2
- 300 : 1
- ... : .

and goes like this

I would like to check every number after "scstatus" and count them and print in ascending or descending order. Here is the code I wrote so far, this script gives me the data above

```
curl -XPOST 'webpage.name.abc' -d { "query": { "filtered": { "query": { "query_string": {
     "analyze_wildcard": true,
     "query": "useragent: \"googlebot\"|\"mediapartners-google\"|\"adsbot-google\""}
 }}},"size": 4000000, "fields": ["@timestamp","servername","uri_path","scstatus","method","cshost","useragent","time-taken","referer","bytes-sent","querystring"]}
```

Comment: "*I want X*" is not a question, let alone a programming question. Did you want to hire a programmer?

Comment: No, sorry for explaining it wrong, it is easy for me to do it c# or java but I am required to create a script that generates a file which contains these information count the occurrence of the numbers and send them by mail, all in the script that runs on the unix server.

Comment: That's still "*I need X*", not a question, let alone a programming question.

Comment: @iondevx, click the "edit" link under your question, and add the code you've written so far that you need help with.

Comment: @ghoti I added the code I wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file format is fixed, this awk one-liner may help:

```
awk -F'"' '$2=="scstatus"{a[$4]++}END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]}' file
200 2
300 1
```

Comment: Thank you @Kent for  providing the solution!